# factoring mapping key in a yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, flatten, pyyaml

I have this YAML file :

```
pb:
  {EF:{16, 19}, EH:{16, 19}}
```

when I apply my `flattendict` Python function, I get this

```
{('pb', 'EF', 16): None,
 ('pb', 'EF', 19): None,
 ('pb', 'EH', 16): None,
 ('pb', 'EH', 19): None}
```

I search the syntax of my YAML file as below, to get the same result (I want factoring my YAML node data)

```
pb:
  {EF, EH}, {16, 19}}
```

Have you an idea?

Here my python flattendict function

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#encoding: UTF-8
import codecs
import sys
import yaml
import pprint

import collections

from collections import Mapping
from itertools import chain
from operator import add

_FLAG_FIRST = object()

def flattenDict(d, join=add, lift=lambda x:x):
    results = []
    def visit(subdict, results, partialKey):
        for k,v in subdict.items():
            newKey = lift(k) if partialKey==_FLAG_FIRST else join(partialKey,lift(k))
            if isinstance(v,Mapping):
                visit(v, results, newKey)
            else:
                results.append((newKey,v))
    visit(d, results, _FLAG_FIRST)
    return results

testdata = yaml.safe_load(open('data.yaml', 'r')) 
from pprint import pprint as pp
result = flattenDict(testdata, lift=lambda x:(x,))
pp(dict(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

In YAML you can have a complex flow node, even in a simple key (i.e. without `?`, markup). This is so in both [YAML 1.2](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#ns-block-simple-key(n)) and [YAML 1.1](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-s-implicit-yaml-key(c)). That means that this:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}: mapping
[1, 2, a]: sequence
```

is correct YAML.

The problem is that a mapping normally loads as a Python `dict` and a sequence as a Python `list`, both of which are mutable, cannot be hashed, and are not allowed as keys for a Python `dict` (try executing `python -c "{{'a': 1}: 2}"`).

PyYAML (which supports YAML 1.1) errors out on both of those lines.

Since Python has an immutable `list` in the form of `tuple`, I decided to implement loading of sequence keys in Python by constructing them as tuples in `ruamel.yaml` (which supports YAML 1.2 and YAML 1.1). So the following works:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pprint import pprint as pp

yaml_str = """\
[pb, EF, 16]: 
[pb, EF, 19]: 
[pb, EH, 16]: 
[pb, EH, 19]: 
"""


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

pp(data)
print('---------')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

printing:

```
{('pb', 'EF', 16): None,
 ('pb', 'EF', 19): None,
 ('pb', 'EH', 16): None,
 ('pb', 'EH', 19): None}
---------
[pb, EF, 16]:
[pb, EF, 19]:
[pb, EH, 16]:
[pb, EH, 19]:
```

If you try to load the above YAML in PyYAML it throws an exception:

```
found unhashable key
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    [pb, EF, 16]:
```

---

Notes:

- If you don't want to round-trip, use `typ="safe"`, it uses the faster C-loader, that also handles keys-that-are-sequences, but it doesn't as smartly dump those back, resulting in `?` marked explicit keys.
- A [proposal for a `frozendict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/) for Python, did not get accepted, so there is no equivalent, not even in the standard library for a `dict` what `tuple` is for a `list`, and `ruamel.yaml` doesn't support mappings as keys out of the box. You can of course add this to `ruamel.yaml`'s Constructor if you have such a frozendict.
- Although there is a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) in Python, and a set in [YAML](http://yaml.org/type/set.html), `ruamel.yaml` does **not** currently accept the following as input:

  ```
  !!set {a , b}: value
  ```
- Probably needless to say: you cannot change the elements of such a key programmatically without deleting and re-adding the key-value pair.